# Show that Young's inequality is an equality if, and only if, $a^p = b^q$.

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

**Show that Young's inequality is an equality if, and only if, $a^p = b^q$**.

Young's inequality says that if $a$, $b$ are real numbers, no
negative and if $p$ and $q$ are conjugated exponents, that is, $1/p + 1/q = 1$, then $ab \leq \frac{1}{p}a^p + \frac{1}{q}b^q$

Now, if $a^p = b^q$, then I have $\frac{1}{p}a^p + \frac{1}{q}b^q =   \frac{1}{p}a^p + \frac{1}{q}a^p =(\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q})a^p = a^p$
but I must have $ab$, so must I prove that $ab = a ^ p$?

The other implication has been more cumbersome for me.

Comment: $ab=a^p$ follows from $1+p/q=p$ (just multiply the equation for the conjugate exponents by $p$).

Comment: For the other direction take the logarithm on both sides and use that the logarithm is strictly concave to get a contradiction.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Now I understand where that equality comes from, but for the other implication I don't quite understand how to get the contradiction using the fact that log is strictly concave. Can you give me more details on this idea please?

Comment: You have $$\log(a)+\log(b)=\log(ab)=\log(1/p a^p +1/q b^q).$$ Now use that the logarithm is strictly concave to show that the rhs is $>\log(a)+\log(b)$ if $a^p\neq b^q$.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Using that logarithm is strictly concave, I have $\log(1/p a^p + 1/q b^q) > 1/p \log(a^p) + 1/q \log(b^q) = \log(a) + \log(b)$ only if $a^p  \neq b^q$, is this correct? and How can I complete what is required?

Comment: $ab = (a^p)^\frac{1}{p}(b^q)^\frac{1}{q}$, now apply $\text{GM}\leq \text{AM}$ and its conditions for equality

Comment: by the way, a common (and useful) way of deducing the case of equality is to go over the proof of the inequality itself step by step and seeing the case of equality in each step. This goes for a lot of the basic inequalities like Young's inequality for products, Holder's inequality, Cauchy-Schwarz (a special case of Holder's inequality) and I'm sure many others.